# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate

I have a web server hosted in AWS ECS using fargate with load balancer.
I added an https listener to the load balancer with a certificate I issued using AWS ACM.
The certificate is issued to a domain I own, the certificate got validated and I'm able to send https requests to the web server via the load balancer using postman.

But, when I open in the browser the url of the load balancer I'm getting the following error
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> what am I doing wrong?

Your SSL cert is issued for your own domain, not for "the url of the load balancer". So it **does not match** and you get the error.

You have to use your own domain now to access your api/website. Browsers are very strict in ensuring that SSL cert and domain match. In terms of postman, you may have disabled these checks, or postman may not be as strict.

You can check postman's ssl checks as shown below:

[image]

Comment: But the load balancer url is auto generated by aws, is there a way to override it? or someother tech in aws that allows something like that?

Comment: @Amitai You have your own domain. You have no control over AWS auto-genrated domain for LB as its owned by AWS.